# Distinct Top Records having huge performance Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables with huge datasets & I am trying to filter the data based on optional search criteria.

```
Table 1 : Item
Table 2 : ScanCode
```

Item can have Zero or n ScanCodes so it's one to 0 or many relation between them  that's why I had left join on ScanCode table, I am trying to get Item data joining with ScanCode with optional search of ScanCode.

```
Declare @p_scanCode BIGINT = NULL, @p_limit INT = 500

SELECT TOP(@p_limit) i.ItemCode, i.StandardDescription,i.ItemType 
FROM Item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN ScanCode sc
ON sc.FK_ItemCode = i.ItemCode
WHERE ((@p_scanCode IS NULL) OR (@p_scanCode IS NOT NULL AND sc.ScanCode = @p_scanCode))
ORDER BY ItemCode
```

Above query works just fine, but since we have multiple ScanCodes for one Item we will be having duplicates in the result set, so I changed the query to include distinct.

```
Declare @p_scanCode BIGINT = NULL, @p_limit INT = 500

SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@p_limit) i.ItemCode, i.StandardDescription,i.ItemType 
FROM Item i
LEFT OUTER JOIN ScanCode sc
ON sc.FK_ItemCode = i.ItemCode
WHERE ((@p_scanCode IS NULL) OR (@p_scanCode IS NOT NULL AND sc.ScanCode = @p_scanCode))
ORDER BY ItemCode
```

After adding distinct on the query, it is now taking more than 30 secs to get results, previously it used to take less than a second. ScanCode table is huge it has 12 million data.

How do I get distinct top records based on limit provided without any peformance issues.

Please suggest.

Comment: For performance related questions we need to see the execution plan.

Comment: Lacking context but it sounds like you have a typical [kitchen sink search issue](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example). And use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is generally a logic flaw.

Comment: Please share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @SMor thank you, the kitchen sink search you gave helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using conditional join & dynamic query would fix the issue, since the problem is with duplicate item when joined with ScanCode table, we can do conditional join if no scancode is provided we don't join so we won't get duplicates. If ScanCode is provided then each scancode will have exactly one item & we won't get duplicates in this case.

Also, OPTION (RECOMPILE) is needed at the end of query if we are using dynamic limits with top(@p_limit) records just so it won't use the cached execution plan with previous limit and performance gets declined.

```
    Declare @p_scanCode BIGINT = '12345', @p_limit INT = 500
    
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
    SELECT TOP(@p_limit) i.ItemCode, i.StandardDescription 
    FROM Item i '
            
    + 
    CASE WHEN @p_scanCode IS NOT NULL THEN
    N' LEFT OUTER JOIN          SCANCODE AS SC
    ON  I.ItemCode = SC.FK_RetailItemCode
    AND GETDATE() BETWEEN SC.EffectiveDate AND SC.TerminationDate ' ELSE N'' END
    +

   'WHERE  1 = 1'
    
    + CASE WHEN @p_scanCode IS NOT NULL THEN
            N' AND sc.ScanCode = @p_scanCode' ELSE N'' END
    +

    ' ORDER BY  I.ItemCode asc OPTION (RECOMPILE)'
    
    print @sql
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to output items from `Item`?  `ScanCode` only comes into play as a filter?  Seems like you need `exists`.  If the relationship is 1:many then you don't need to worry about `distinct`.

```
declare 
    @p_scanCode bigint = null, 
    @p_limit int = 500

select      
top (@p_limit)  i.ItemCode, i.StandardDescription,i.ItemType 
from            item i
where           @p_scanCode is null
or              exists (
                    select    0
                    from      scanCode sc
                    where     sc.FK_ItemCode = i.ItemCode
                    and       scanCode = @p_scanCode
                )
```

Comment: I cannot use exists in the where clause, as scanCode is optional, we can have 0 or n number of scancode, so I had left join with optional search criteria

Comment: Sorry, I reworked the filters to meet that need.  If p_scancode is null, then all records output, else just the ones with an existing p_scanCode.  Is this correct for your need?

Comment: thanks pwilcox, but they could optionally pass p_scanCode  as filter & if they pass the p_scanCode I need to filter only matching scancode Item else get top 500 also Item can have a Zero or n ScanCodes, if i put scanCode = @p_Scancode inside subquery it's taking alot of time to get results

Comment: I edited again to match your last statement: 'If i put scanCode = @p_scancode inside subquery ...'.  I thought I did that, but must have deleted too much.  Sorry it's making it slow though.  Hopefully someone else has a good solution.

Comment: @VR1256 I would go with this as being better than your existing code, but perhaps refactor the `OR` into either an `IF/ELSE` with two separate queries, or a `UNION ALL`. An `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint may help also. See also https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example

Comment: @Charlieface mentions the possibility of `union all`.  That enters my mind in two ways.  But the one I'd be curious if it helps would be to append `... and @p_scanCode is not null union all select 0 where @p_scanCode is null` to the end of the query inside `exists`.

Comment: Not inside the `exists`, a whole separate query

Comment: Thanks everyone figured out the solution with conditional joins and dynamic query

Comment: Just be careful.  Dynamic query sounds like a band-aid.  I'd keep looking at a non-dynamic solution in the long term.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but in this case with dynamic top limit and distinct in place, query takes forever.. dynamic query is getting results in milli seconds.. also I wrote stored procedure and took care of SQL injection issue as well